# Como criar chave composta com Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Tenho meu model base que todas as classes herdam dele:

```
public class Base 
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public int ClienteId {get;set;}
}
```

E um exemplo de model:

```
public class Grupo: Base
{
   public string Nome {get;set;}
}
```

E um subgrupo

```
public class SubGrupo:Base
{
  public int GrupoId {get;set;}
  public string Nome {get;set;}
}
```

Gostaria que criasse uma chave composta, por exemplo:

```
foreign key (grupo_id, cliente_id) references cliente (id, cliente_id)
```

Como faço isso?

Comment: No exemplo de SQL que você passou, cliente_id são dois campos em duas tabelas distintas, mas no seu código a herança faz com que só exista 1 ClientId. Eu particularmente não entendi o que você deseja, você desenhou um comando de foreign key, esse comando estaria na tabela Subgrupo? A Table Base existe? Uma resposta de qualidade precisa de mais detalhes do que você deseja alcançar, Modelo e Tabela são coisas distintas, deixe mais explicito o que você quer, você usou um nome de tabela que não corresponde aos modelos mostrados, não informou em qual tabela colocou esse foreign key.

Comment: Ola @Malkaviano, o em SQL é em postgress, o ex dos modelos a geração é via code first, o intuito final é a proteção de uma APP multitenant que compartilha o mesmo dB, um ex da vuln seria eu mudar o valor de um grupo que esta em outro tenant e salvar em meu subgrupo... Em SQL eu sei proteger, mas não sei ao gerar o sb com codefirst

Comment: Base é concreta e pode ter representação física ou ela é uma abstract class?

Comment: Apenas abstract, para todos os modelo serem gerados com as propriedades dela...id, createdate, clienteid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por `Attributes` não poderia haver herança. Ficaria assim:

```
public class Subgrupo 
{
   [Key]
   public int Id {get;set;}
   [ForeignKey("Cliente"), Column(Order = 0)]
   public int GrupoId {get;set;}
   [ForeignKey("Cliente"), Column(Order = 1)]
   public int ClienteId {get;set;}

   public string Nome {get;set;}

   public virtual Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
}

public class Grupo 
{
   [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
   public int Id {get;set;}
   [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
   public int ClienteId {get;set;}

   ...
}
```

Comment: utilizando a classe "Base" não é possível ? tenho inúmeras classes que herdam, apenas de não ter muitas propriedades dentro dela.

Aproveitando esse comentário, o que está usando para gerar pdf? rs itextsharp agora é agpl, ou seja, não comercial =/

Comment: Pra classe `Base`, `GrupoId` precisaria estar em `Base` também.

Comment: Sobre o PDF, [continuo mantendo meu pacote, RazorPDF2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RazorPDF2/).

Comment: Ele usa itextsharp, está com a versão que é licença GPL ou AGPL ?

Comment: Licença Apache, na verdade. https://github.com/DesignLiquido/RazorPDF2/blob/master/License.txt

Answer (score 2):

Eu faço via `Fluent Api`

um exemplo, não é possível incluir uma cidade com o mesmo nome para o mesmo estado, ficando assim meu indice

```
this.Property(a => a.Descricao)
                .HasColumnAnnotation("Index",
                    new IndexAnnotation(new[]
                        {
                            new IndexAttribute("IX_Cidade_Descricao_Unique")
                            {
                                IsUnique = true, 
                                Order=0
                            }
                        }));
            this.Property(a => a.EstadoId)
                .HasColumnAnnotation("Index",
                    new IndexAnnotation(new[]
                        {
                            new IndexAttribute("IX_Cidade_Descricao_Unique")
                            {
                                IsUnique = true, 
                                Order=1
                            }
                        }));
```

Answer (score 1):

Apenas complementando a resposta do @CiganoMorrisonMendez, pois acredito que seja a melhor resposta.

Você pode manter a sua estrutura e adicionar uma ForeignKey a uma propriedade herdada, porem para isto você terá que usar um MetadaType.

```
public class Base 
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int Id {get;set;}

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int ClienteId {get;set;}
}

public class Grupo: Base
{
    public string Nome {get;set;}
}

[MetadataType(typeof(FK_Grupo_SubGrupo))]
public class SubGrupo:Base
{
    public int GrupoId {get;set;}
    public string Nome {get;set;}
}

public class FK_Grupo_SubGrupo
{
    [ForeignKey("Grupo"), Column(Order = 0)]
    public int GrupoId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Grupo"), Column(Order = 1)]
    public int ClienteId { get; set; }
}
```

Mas sinceramente, não acho que vala a pena.

Answer (score 0):

Editei para por mais uma opção no final.

Se eu entendi certo, Grupo manda em Subgrupo, ou seja, o subgrupo está amarrado ao grupo. O ClienteId deixei de fora, porque a chave estrangeira está na entidade errada e ClientId nunca será candidata a chave primária em outra entidade, leia as opções abaixo.

```
    public abstract class Base
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int ClienteId { get; set; }
    }

    public class Grupo : Base
    {
        public string Nome { get; set; }
    }

    public class SubGrupo : Base
    {        
        public int GrupoId { get; set; }

        public string Nome { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("GrupoId")]
        public Grupo Grupo { get; set; }
    }
```

Perceba que se você incluir foreing key em ClienteId o EF irá reclamar de CASCADE ciclico, porque ele recai sobre ambas as classes Grupo e Subgrupo, nesse caso você pode tanto avisar o EF para não fazer CASCADE como mover o ClienteId para Grupo.

Existem meios polimórficos de fazer isso no BD, mas fica pra outra ocasião.

Eu enxergo as restrições dessa forma

```
public abstract class Base
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }        
    }

    public class Grupo : Base
    {
        public string Nome { get; set; }

        public int ClienteId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ClienteId")]
        public Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
    }

    public class SubGrupo : Base
    {        
        public int GrupoId { get; set; }

        public string Nome { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("GrupoId")]
        public Grupo Grupo { get; set; }
    }

    public class Cliente
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
```

Que geram esses esquemas:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Grupoes] (
    [Id]        INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Nome]      NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [ClienteId] INT            NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Grupoes] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Grupoes_dbo.Clientes_ClienteId] FOREIGN KEY ([ClienteId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Clientes] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SubGrupoes] (
    [Id]      INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [GrupoId] INT            NOT NULL,
    [Nome]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.SubGrupoes] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.SubGrupoes_dbo.Grupoes_GrupoId] FOREIGN KEY ([GrupoId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Grupoes] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

O resto é JOIN.

Vou incluir uma opção Many-To-Many para deixar mais completo.

```
public abstract class Base
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }        
    }

    public class Grupo : Base
    {
        public string Nome { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Cliente> Clientes { get; set; }

        public Grupo()
        {
            Clientes = new Collection<Cliente>();
        }
    }

    public class SubGrupo : Base
    {        
        public int GrupoId { get; set; }

        public string Nome { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("GrupoId")]
        public Grupo Grupo { get; set; }
    }

    public class Cliente
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Grupo> Grupos { get; set; }

        public Cliente()
        {
            Grupos = new Collection<Grupo>();
        }
    }
```

O EF cria a tabela intermediária com as chaves foreign e primária composta:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[GrupoClientes] (
    [Grupo_Id]   INT NOT NULL,
    [Cliente_Id] INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.GrupoClientes] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Grupo_Id] ASC, [Cliente_Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.GrupoClientes_dbo.Grupoes_Grupo_Id] FOREIGN KEY ([Grupo_Id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Grupoes] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.GrupoClientes_dbo.Clientes_Cliente_Id] FOREIGN KEY ([Cliente_Id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Clientes] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Answer (score -1):

@Rod lendo melhor sua dúvida, acredito o que você esta tentando fazer é o seguinte.

No exemplo criei duas entidade, `Pessoa` e `Pedido`, onde a minha entidade `Pessoa` tem chave primaria composta pelas colunas `ClienteId` e `Cpf`, sendo essa entidade um relacionamento de 1 para muitos com `Pedido` sendo necessário termos as propriedades `ClienteId` e `Cpf` na nossa entidade `Pedido`.

Ficando o código da seguinte forma

```
public partial class Cliente
    {
        public Cliente()
        {
            this.Pedidoes = new List<Pedido>();
        }

        public int ClienteId { get; set; }
        public string Cpf { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Pedido> Pedidoes { get; set; }
    }

public partial class Pedido
    {
        public int PedidoId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> ClienteId { get; set; }
        public string Cpf { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Numero { get; set; }
        public virtual Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
    }

public class ClienteMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Cliente>
    {
        public ClienteMap()
        {
            // Primary Key
            this.HasKey(t => new { t.ClienteId, t.Cpf });

            // Properties
            this.Property(t => t.ClienteId)
                .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

            this.Property(t => t.Cpf)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(50);

            this.Property(t => t.Nome)
                .IsFixedLength()
                .HasMaxLength(10);

            // Table & Column Mappings
            this.ToTable("Cliente");
            this.Property(t => t.ClienteId).HasColumnName("ClienteId");
            this.Property(t => t.Cpf).HasColumnName("Cpf");
            this.Property(t => t.Nome).HasColumnName("Nome");
        }
    }

public class PedidoMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Pedido>
    {
        public PedidoMap()
        {
            // Primary Key
            this.HasKey(t => t.PedidoId);

            // Properties
            this.Property(t => t.PedidoId)
                .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

            this.Property(t => t.Cpf)
                .HasMaxLength(50);

            // Table & Column Mappings
            this.ToTable("Pedido");
            this.Property(t => t.PedidoId).HasColumnName("PedidoId");
            this.Property(t => t.ClienteId).HasColumnName("ClienteId");
            this.Property(t => t.Cpf).HasColumnName("Cpf");
            this.Property(t => t.Numero).HasColumnName("Numero");

            // Relationships
            this.HasOptional(t => t.Cliente)
                .WithMany(t => t.Pedidoes)
                .HasForeignKey(d => new { d.ClienteId, d.Cpf });

        }
    }
```