# Tabela não aparece em modelos EDMX

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Estou com um problema em uma aplicação que estou desenvolvendo, eu criei os modelos usando o ADO.NET Entity Data Model.

Porém uma tabela especifica não esta aparecendo segue abaixo o script que estou usando para criar a tabela, ela esta criada e funciona porém não é criado modelo para ela.

Script SQL que estou usando para criar a tabela

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table tb_r_veiculo_adicionais
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE  tb_r_veiculo_adicionais (
  veiculo INT NOT NULL,
  adicional INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (veiculo, adicional),
  FOREIGN KEY (veiculo) REFERENCES tb_veiculo (codigo),
  FOREIGN KEY (adicional) REFERENCES tb_adicionais (codigo)
)
```

Segue abaixo o erro retornado

> Error 1   Error 3003: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 528:Given the cardinality of Association End Member tb_veiculo, it should be mapped to key columns of the table tb_r_veiculo_adicionais. Either fix the mapping or change the multiplicity of this end.
>   C:\Users\Hiago\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ProjetoJonathan\ProjetoJonathan\projeto_jonathan.edmx  529 11  ProjetoJonathan

**Observação:** Ao apagar o EDMX e criar funciona, só que o modelo da tabela `tb_r_veiculo_adicionais` não é gerado.

**ATUALIZAÇÃO**: Percebi que o problema só ocorre quando eu crio as foreign keys.

Comment: vc definiu o codigo como PK na tabela tb_veiculo ?

Comment: Sim coloquei, se quiserem eu posto o SQL inteiro.

Comment: Não lembro bem agora, mas acho que é por causa das chaves compostas `PRIMARY KEY (veiculo, adicional),` tente por um Id na tabela como `PK ` no lugar de chave composta.

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza é uma exigência eu ter a chave composta, e as foreign keys... não posso mudar eles. Será que há alguma outra maneira?

Comment: Veja [link](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/50459/como-criar-chave-composta-com-entity-framework-6)

Comment: Camarada, Isto acontece porque a sua tabela apenas possui campos que são chaves primárias ou estrangeiras.

Comment: Sim, mas sabe me explicar o motivo dele não aceitar a tabela nessas condições? Pois as mesmas estão normalizadas, não estão fora de padrão.

Comment: Ex: muito simples. Olhe o seguinte código:
db.TbMusicas.Find(musi.IDMusica).TbEstilosMusica.Add(estil);

Onde:
db = EntityModel; 
TbMusicas = Nome da tabela Mãe; 
Musi.idMusica = Id do valor que procuro na tabela de músicas; 
TbEstilosMusica = Nome data tabela mãe que contém varios estilos de música (Nota: possuo uma tabela filha de TbMusicas que faz ligação com a tabela TbEstilosMusica. Esta dita tabela chama-se TbMusicas_Estilos); 
estil = é um valor encontrado em TbEstilosMusica;

Parece um pouco confuse, mas é muito simples.

Fico a espera do feedback.

Comment: sim mais qual seria a razão dele não gerar um EDMX? Tem algo oficial sobre isso? é um problema? não é? estou fazendo errado?

Comment: Eu já entreguei o trabalho, só queria entender o porque não funcionou com as FK

Comment: Não é nenhum problema. É um princío de classes em Programação Orientada à Objectos. E o EDMX (ou Entity) funciona com base em classes. Quando uma classe possui apenas "chaves estrangeiras" como probpriedades/variáveis, a maneira como se deve trabalhar com esta classe torna-se um pouco diferente.

Answer (score 2):

Tabelas como `tb_r_veiculo_adicionais` são chamadas de tabelas de relacionamento. Basicamente, esse tipo de tabela não tem significado de negócio, constituem apenas uma maneira de modelar relacionacionamentos *n-para-m* no mundo relacional.

No mundo Orientado a Objetos você não precisa de uma entidade de suporte para representar esse relacionamento. Basta que `Veiculo` possua uma coleção de *adicionais* e `Adicional` possua uma coleção de *veiculos*:

```
public class Veiculo
{
   public int VeiculoId { get; set; }
   // demais propriedades
   public virtual ICollection <Adicional> Adicionais { get; set; }
}
```

E o mapeamento:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Veiulo>()
            .HasMany(v => v.Adicionais)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(x =>
            {
                x.MapLeftKey("veiculo");
                x.MapRightKey("adicional");
                x.ToTable("tb_r_veiculo_adicionais");
            });
```

Esse é um dos muitos exemplos em que o modelo relacional e o modelo orientado a objetos não casam 100%. Em inglês o termo técnico para essas diferenças e problemas de mapeamento é [*object-relational impedance mismatch*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_impedance_mismatch).

No momento em que você pede para o Visual Studio fazer engenharia reserva do seu banco de dados, ele adota por padrão a estratégia de esconder a tabela de relacionamentos. Isso não é um problema, é uma *feature*.

Nada te impede de editar o modelo gerado para incluir uma entidade de relacionamento explícita se essa for necessária (por exemplo, se existirem atributos de relacionamento na tabela `tb_r_veiculo_adicionais`). Você pode sempre editar suas entidades manualmente. Veja [esse exemplo no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16802518/664577) sobre como fazer isso.

Além disso, conforme outras respostas já apontaram, existem muitas maneiras de "forçar" a criação de uma entidade para representar uma tabela de relacionamento durante o processo de engenharia reversa do banco (se, por qualquer motivo, você não quiser editar o modelo manualmente). Uma opção além daquelas que já foram apontadas é adicionar uma coluna temporária à tabela `tb_r_veiculo_adicionais` para forçar a engenharia reversa da mesma. Depois de fazer a engenharia reserva do banco você pode apagar a coluna temporária e fazer um *refresh* do modelo (veja [essa resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18302177/664577) para mais detalhes).

Answer (score -1):

Já tive esse problema. Resolvi criando uma coluna na tabela chamada Id do tipo int, como chave primária com Identity. O EF, se perde com chaves compostas.
Faça o teste.

Comment: André Monteiro, gostaria de saber o porque com a chave composta não cria. Nesse caso tem que fazer o projeto com o banco de dados fornecido pela universidade. =/

Comment: Hiago, mande os scripts das tabelas estrangeiras (tb_veiculo e tb_adicionais) que vou realizar os testes.