# Update , Insert no entity Framework Usando View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Estou com um erro no meu projeto ao tentar dar um *Update* ou um *Insert* via Entity Framework, onde eu mapeei uma *view* de banco de dados.

Li no stackoverflow inglês que não consigo realizar *update* ou *insert* via *view* porque não existe uma *primary key* definida.

Vi também que dá pra mudar isso, mas não consegui encontrar onde. Alguém sabe como corrigir este erro? Onde consigo configurar o `.edmx` para aceitar *Updates* mesmo não tento uma *primary key* definida?

Ou devo mapear uma tabela mesmo?

[image: Erro No Visual Studio]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Estou com um erro no meu projeto ao tentar dar um Update ou um Insert via Entity Framework, onde eu mapeei uma view de banco de dados.

[De acordo com a documentação oficial do SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms187956(v=sql.120).aspx) (veja *Updatable Views*):

> É possível modificar os dados de uma tabela base subjacente através de uma exibição, contanto que as seguintes condições sejam verdadeiras:
>
> - Todas as modificações, inclusive as instruções UPDATE, INSERT e DELETE, devem referenciar colunas de apenas uma tabela base.
> - As colunas a serem modificadas na exibição devem referenciar diretamente os dados subjacentes das colunas da tabela. As colunas não podem ser derivadas de qualquer outro modo, como pelo seguinte:
>
>   - Uma função de agregação: AVG, COUNT, SUM, MIN, MAX, GROUPING, STDEV, STDEVP, VAR e VARP.
>   - Uma computação. A coluna não pode ser computada de uma expressão que utiliza outras colunas. As colunas formadas com o uso dos operadores de conjunto UNION, UNION ALL, CROSSJOIN, EXCEPT e INTERSECT resultam em uma computação e também não são atualizáveis.
> - As colunas modificadas não são afetadas pelas cláusulas GROUP BY, HAVING ou DISTINCT.
> - TOP não é usado em nenhum lugar na select_statement da exibição junto com a cláusula WITH CHECK OPTION.

Se sua *view* não segue estas condições, não vai funcionar. E isto não depende do Entity Framework.

> Li no stackoverflow inglês que não consigo realizar *update* ou *insert* via *view* porque não existe uma *primary key* definida. Vi também que dá pra mudar isso, mas não consegui encontrar onde. Alguém sabe como corrigir este erro? Onde consigo configurar o `.edmx` para aceitar *Updates* mesmo não tento uma *primary key* definida?

Isto não é um erro. É uma condição essencial para que o *framework* funcione. O erro é todo seu.

Para funcionar, você precisa definir pelo menos um campo como *primary key*. Pode ser mais de um, aliás.

O modelador de EDMX não é a ferramenta mais adequada para isso. Você terá que decorar seu *Model* gerado pelo EDMX com atributos de chave primária. [Veja aqui um exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/50459/como-criar-chave-composta-com-entity-framework-6/51339#51339).

Comment: Adicionei a seguinte linha .
        [Key]
        public int CódigodaTabela { get; set; }
no Arquivo de extensão .tt porem ainda recebo a mesma mensagem do Visual Studio. Sabe o que pode ser ?

Comment: Melhor desistir do EDMX e aterar tudo no `.cs`.

Comment: Consegui Resolver , Valew pela Ajuda Cigano .
Eu Fui no XML do Entity alterei algumas propriedades e funcionou perfeitamente Obrigado.

Comment: Jovem, [leia isto aqui, por favor](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour). Aproveite e edite sua pergunta para colocar como você resolveu o problema. Obrigado!