# Mapeamento de chave composta entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dataannotations

Boa tarde,

Como faço para mapear chave composta nas minhas entidades, no caso a 1 entidade chama documento e a PK dela é pela propriedade ID e WEBID, e ela faz FK com a Usuario como eu faria nesse caso?

Documento

```
    public class Documento : IAggregate
    {
        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 1)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 2)]
        public int WebId{ get; set; }
        public int UsuarioId { get; set; }
        public string Situacao { get; set; }
        public string Numero { get; set; }
        public string Enviadoar { get; set; }
        public DateTime DataCriacao { get; set; }
        public virtual Usuario Usuario { get; set; }
}
```

Usuario:

```
public class Usuario : IAggregate
    {
        [Key]
        public int UsuarioId { get; set; }
        public string CodigoUsuario { get; set; }
        [Key]
        public int WebId{ get; set; }

        public string Codigo { get; set; }

        public int NumeracaoAtual { get; set; }

        public DateTime Ano { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Documento> Documentos { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como criar chave composta com Entity Framework 6](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/50459/como-criar-chave-composta-com-entity-framework-6)

Comment: A pergunta é a mesma, minha entidade está da mesma forma porem o erro persiste por isso postei aqui, o erro que ocorre é: Unable to determine composite primary key ordering for type 'Teste.Domain.Model.Documento'. Use the ColumnAttribute (see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=386388) or the HasKey method (see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=386387) to specify an order for composite primary keys.